Projective representation of hyperbolic geometry from conformal representation
I'm reading «Road to reality» written by Penrose and I ran into a problem trying to prove that projective representation of hyperbolic geometry may be obtained form the conformal one by means of expansion radially out from an amount given by $\frac{2R^2}{R^2+(r_c)^2}$ where $R$ is the radius of the bounding circle and $r_c$ is the Euclidean distance out from the center of the bounding  circle of a point in the conformal representation.
Trying hard I couldn't prove that (maybe because I'm weak in geometry). The author writes that  one can use Beltrami's geometry but I couldn't get the clue.
I'm asking the community to help me with it because without the proving I can't go further in reading the book.

Do you mean correspondences like in the sixth figure in this Wikipedia article ? Or similar fig 5 here ?

I am definitely very sorry. But you are right. That's exactly the kind of correspondence.
